# cakePHP security: can others view/tamper variables i set for my views?

Tags: php, security, cakephp, authentication, authorization

I have a cakePHP application with user authentication by means of 'Auth' component.
 In order to customize views based on user role, I added below lines to my code:

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
    ....
    $this->set('loggedIn', $this->Auth->user('id'));
    $this->set('role',$this->Auth->user('role'));
    ....
}
```

So inside my .ctp view files i will check user role (admin,user,moderator,...) and then change the view using if/elses to be fit with user role.
I want to know are end-users of application can tamper '$role' such that they can change behaivour of application or all of aspects of application will be handled on server side and this type of View customization is safe enough?

Comment: please put your answer in answers section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No it *should* not be possible. But it really depends on how secure your application is written. CakePHP by default is a pretty solid and secure framework, there has been only one or two serios issues in the last ~5 years as far as I remember.

First you should use the [security component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) to avoid form tampering. For example I could go to my profile, add a hidden field "role" and set it's value to "admin" and submit. My role will be updated in the DB and I'm an admin.

Another possibility could be file uploads that aren't properly checked. Many people like to forget calling is_uploaded_file(). Most stupid example: I upload a php file, it ends up in app/webroot/uploads/hack.php and I can execute it by calling foo.com/uploads/hack.php and then do whatever I want in the worst case, for example modifying files of your application. Even if your app is properly set up and the application files are read only, I could still read the app/Config/database.php and then do whatever I want with the credentials. So make sure your file system permissions are correctly configured. Only app/tmp should be writeable.

From where ever input comes from, POST, GET, a csv file, human generated or machine generate, when you process it you **always** want to validate it and make sure that the incoming data is sanitized and validated. Trust nobody is a pretty basic security rule.

Comment: is it possible to do such a thing on user side: 'I could go to my profile, add a hidden field "role" and set it's value to "admin" and submit'? can you provide some programming samples and details about this?

Comment: Use the inspector and just manipulate the form or use a tool like cURL or Postman, and send a modified form. The security component prevents the user from manipulating forms. When you work with dynamic forms, form inputs that were created with JS, you'll have to whitelist them and validate that no unwanted data comes through. Read the security component page I've linked and use Google to find details about the attacks it can prevent.

Answer (score 1):

The only way they can tamper with those settings is if they are able to access the files directly. They would need direct access to editing your files by accessing your server and the files on it.

Comment: That's not the only way, there other ways you can modify that information.

Comment: I thought there might be. How else?